# mmap(): Is it possible to prevent writing back to file with MAP_SHARED flag?

Tags: mmap

As I understand, 'MAP_SHARED' flag in mmap() shares any changes made by a process to the memory map immediately with other processes and eventually writes the changes back to the file. Is it possible to share the in-memory changes with other processes but not write the changes back to file? Does it need a new type of flag? How complex would be to implement that kind of flag (e.g. 'MAP_SHARED_NOT_WRITE_BACK)?

=======================================

**Added:** The usecase I have in mind: Process *A* mmap's the code segment of a shared library foo.so and makes changes to the code (for example, encrypt the code). I want other processes *B*, *C*, etc. created later on and using *foo.so* share the modified code. I, however, don't want the changes written back to *foo.so* file. I would prefer a scalable solution that works for multiple processes and many shared libraries.

Comment: Does it have to come from a file originally? Can you use some non-file-backed mapping (`shm_open()`?) and just seed it with the file data?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've updated my original post and would like to know if you have any suggestion for a scalable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr; you should use a file which only lives in RAM

like on Linux are the files returned by `memfd_create(2)` or by opening a file from a `tmpfs` filesystem [1].

In that case the memory will be backed by the *swap* instead of a regular file or device -- if there's any swap configured. Beware that if the file is big, this will put pressure on your system and severely degrade its performance for zero benefit.

NB: If you're concerned about your "secrets" being inadvertently written to permanent storage, better look into what encrypted storage solutions there are for your system.

[1] `shm_open(3)` is implemented on Linux by simply opening a file on a tmpfs mounted on `/dev/shm`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've updated my original post and would like to know if you have any suggestion for a scalable solution.

Comment: Please explain what's not "scalable" about it. You can create shared libraries on a tmpfs, then point other programs there with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (or some other solution, like an overlay mount)

Comment: I said in the context of what you mentioned: `Beware that if the file is big, this will put pressure on your system and severely degrade its performance for zero benefit.` Is it reasonable to open all the shared libraries from tmpfs without performance degradation?